# GPS data being retrieved is unintelligible

Tags: gps

I am trying to use a vk-162 gps usb to get gps information. Earlier this month i succeeded in displaying information but the sd card of my raspberry pi got corrupted so I had to install a new os with a new and card. I followed the same steps I took to get the gps data originally but I haven’t been able to get it to work. Whenever I run cat to check the gps data that is being produced I can’t seem to make anything of it.

Steps I took:

```
cd /dev/
ls
sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients 
sudo systemctl stop gpsd.socket
sudo systemctl disable gpsd.socket
vim /lib/systemd/system/gpsd.socket
sudo kilall gpsd
sudo gpsd /dev/ttyACM0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

Output whenever I display with cat:

```
group26@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /dev/ttyACM0
$GPTXT,01,01,02,u-blox ag - www.u-blox.com*50

$GPTXT,01,01,02,HW  UBX-G70xx   00070000 FF7FFFFFo*69

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ROM CORE 1.00 (59842) Jun 27 2012 17:43:52*59

$GPTXT,01,01,02,PROTVER 14.00*1E

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSUPERV=AC SD PDoS SR*20

$GPTXT,01,01,02,ANTSTATUS=OK*3B

$GPTXT,01,01,02,LLC FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFF-FFFFFFFD*2C

�b4�[� L�C���Q�b����(}�b4�_� L�C���͵b����9�b4�c� L�C���I�b������b4�g� L�C����b����챵b4�k� L�C�����m�b4po� L�C � ����b�����)�b4Xs� L�C
� �qA�b������b4@w� L�C
� �]��b�������b4({� L�C
                           � �Ka�b�����]�b4� L�C
                                                   � �6ɵb����t�b4��� L�C
                                                                           � �U�b����_Ƶb4��� L�C&@��&�'�� � ��b����K��b4Ȋ� L�C�� ��2�b����7>�b4��� L�C����b�����b������b4��� L�C�̰�b�����r�b4h�� L�C�bh��'''''''+��b h�������.�b4P�� L�C�׵b/�b P��������b48�� L�C�3�bõb 8���������b4 �� L�C���b�����b�b�� L�C����'''''''��b��������b4� L�C�7�b�'''''''�n�b ������˵b4ر� L�C]��bر�'''''''��b ر�����n��b4��� L�CI��b���'''''''���b �������ZC�b4��� L�C5T�b���'''''''�*�b �������F��b4���!��b���'''''''v��b �������2��b4x��
```

Could someone explain what this data is and why it is this way?

Comment: could be binary data

Comment: What happens if you control-C out of the CAT & start the CAT up again? Does it work for a few lines and then get corrupted again? BTW, you probably only need the SYSTEMCTL STOP if you don't reboot.

Comment: Has there been any baud rate mismatch anywhere? Because this type of garbage values usually appears when the baud rate of two communicating devices do not match.